# Windows 8 blue screen error

Tags: windows-8, drivers

While I was installing a driver for my Wi-Fi card on my acer aspire one netbook, which I downloaded from  Acer website my netbook shows a blue screen error saying that your pc ecountered an error that could not handle and it needed to restart. Then it showed the following error:  Driver IRQL less or equal.
It restarted my computer and the error showed up again.
How can I fix this error and recover the windows?
Information for the computer:
I don' t have any other pc, and this computer has an old bios NOT UEFI. The model is an acer aspire one AO531h-0bk.
To fix the computer I have a windows fix disk, and several Linux Ubuntu installation DVDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Shift-F8 to get into the troubleshooting options, then use System Restore.

Details are here: http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/

...except that you don't need "Safe Mode". Follow that until you see the "Advanced" screen, then choose "System Restore".

Comment: After I followed your instructions, Windows restarted and loaded successfully. But then showed up a window saying that windows had a problem caused to restart the computer with the following details: C:\windows\minidump\090914-30747-01.dump
C:\users\john\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-82399-0.sys data.xml
C:\windows\Memory.DMP
I sent a bug message on microsoft as I was asked to, but my computer didn't restart and I could use it.

Comment: After 2 hours while I was using windows properly, it said again that windows had a problem caused the computer to restart. My computer restarted and windows loaded again

Comment: _"But then showed up a window saying that windows had a problem caused to restart_" - that was a report of the previous crash.